# creating new user gender doesnt appier

Tags: javascript, node.js

Hi when i creating new user from website a gender doesnt displaying . At the top everything is displaying like need to be displayed first tree users are maked with postman app on the bottom maked from website and doesnt display gender place code is below . thanks

```
<%for(var i = 0; i <users.length; i++){%>

<tr>
    <td><%= i + 1%></td>
    <td><%=users[i].name%></td>
    <td><%=users[i].email%></td>
    <td><%=users[i].gender%></td>
    <td><%=users[i].status%></td>
    <td>
        <a href="/update-user?id=<%=users[i]._id%>" class="btn border-shadow update">
            <span class="text-gradient"><i class="fas fa-user-edit"></i></span>
        </a>
        <a class="btn border-shadow delete">
         <span class="text-gradient"><i class="fas fa-user-slash"></i></span>
     </a>
    </td>
</tr>
<%}%>
```

form.ejs code here

```
<!-- form handling -->
<form action="/api/users" method="POST" id="add_user">
    <div class="new_user">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="name" class="text-light">Vardas</label>
            <input type="hidden" name="id" value="">             
                <input type="text" name="name" value="" placeholder="Vardenis">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email" class="text-light">Email</label>       
            <input type="text" name="email" value="" placeholder="pavizdys@gmail.com">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="Lytis" class="text-light">Lytis</label>
    <div class="radio inline">
               <input type="radio" id="radio-2" name="Lytis" value="Vyras">
               <label for="radio-2" class="radio-label">Vyras</label>
            </div>       
            <div class="radio inline">
                <input type="radio" id="radio-3" name="Lytis" value="Moteris">
                <label for="radio-3" class="radio-label">Moteris</label>
             </div> 
        </div>
    
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="Lytis" class="text-light">Statusas</label>
            <div class="radio inline">
                       <input type="radio" id="radio-4" name="status" value="Prisijunges">
                       <label for="radio-4" class="radio-label">Aktyvus</label>
                    </div>       
                    <div class="radio inline">
                        <input type="radio" id="radio-5" name="status" value="Atsijunges">
                        <label for="radio-5" class="radio-label">Neaktyvus</label>
                     </div> 
                </div>
    <div class="form-group">
       <button type="submit" class="btn text-dark update">Išsaugoti</button> 
    </div>
    
            </div>
    </form>    

render.js

const axios = require('axios');



exports.homeRoutes = (req,res)=>{
    // Make a get request to api users
    axios.get('http://localhost:3000/api/users')
    .then(function(response){  
         
        res.render('index',{users: response.data});
    })
    .catch(err=>{
        res.send(err);
    })
      
}

exports.add_user = (req,res)=>{
    res.render("add_user");
}

exports.update_user = (req,res)=>{
   axios.get('http://localhost:3000/api/users',{params:{id:req.query.id}})
    .then(function(userdata){
res.render("update_user",{user:userdata.data})
    })
   .catch(err=>{
       res.send(err);
   })
}

server.js code below

const express = require('express');
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
const morgan = require('morgan');
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const path = require('path');

const connectDB = require('./server/database/connection');

const app= express();

dotenv.config( {path :'config.env'} )
const PORT= process.env.PORT||8080

//log requests
app.use(morgan('tiny'));

// mongoDB connection

connectDB();

// parse request to body-parses

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
//app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}))

//set view engine
app.set("view engine","ejs")
//app.set("views",path.resolve(__dirname,"views/ejs"))

//load assets
app.use('/css',express.static(path.resolve(__dirname,"assets/css")))
app.use('/img',express.static(path.resolve(__dirname,"assets/img")))
app.use('/js',express.static(path.resolve(__dirname,"assets/js")))
//css/style.css



//load routes

app.use('/',require('./server/routes/router'))

app.listen(PORT,()=>{console.log(`Server is running on http://localhost:${PORT}`)});


controller.js

const { response } = require('express');
let Userdb = require('../model/model');

// create and save new user object

exports.create = (req,res)=>{
   // validate requast
   if(!req.body){
       res.status(400).send({ message: "Laukas negali būti tusčias!" })
       return;
   }


   // new user
   const user = new Userdb({
      name:req.body.name,
      email:req.body.email,
      gender:req.body.gender,
      status:req.body.status
   })

   // save user to database
   user
   .save(user)
   .then(data =>{
      //res.send(data)
      res.redirect('/add-user')
    })
   .catch(err =>{
       res.status(500).send({
           message : err.message ||'Kuriant kūrimo operaciją įvyko klaida'
       });
   });
}


// retrieve and ruturn all users

exports.find = (req, res) =>{
    Userdb.find()

 if(req.query.id){
  const id = req.query.id;

  Userdb.findById(id)
  .then(data=>{
      if(!data){
          res.status(404).send({message:"Nerastas naudotojas su id"+ id})
      }else{
         res.send(data) 
      }
  })
  .catch(err=>{
      res.status(500).send({message:"Error gaunant naudojo id"+ id})
  })

 }else{
    Userdb.find()
    .then(user => {
        res.send(user)
    })
    .catch(err => {
        res.status(500).send({message: err.message || "Gaunant naudotojo informaciją įvyko klaida"})
    })
 }

  
}

// update a new user by id

exports.update = (req, res) => {
    if(!req.body){
        return res
        .status(400)
        .send({message:"Atnaujinant duomenis laukai negali būti tušti!"})
    }

   const id=req.params.id;
  Userdb.findByIdAndUpdate(id,req.body,{useFindAndModify:false})
  .then(data =>{
      if(!data){
          res.status(404).send({message: `Negalima atnaujinti naudotojo su ${id}.Naudotojas nerastas!`})
      }else{
          res.send(data)
      }
  })
  .catch(err =>{
      res.status(500).send({message:"Error atnaujinti nepavyko"})
  })
}


// Delete a user with user id

exports.delete = (req, res,) => {
   const id=req.params.id;

   Userdb.findByIdAndDelete(id)
   .then(data=>{
       if(!data){
           res.status(404).send({message:`Negalima ištrinti su id ${id}. Blogas id`})
       }else{
          res.send({
              message: "Naudotojas ištrintas!"
          }) 
       }
   })
   .catch(err =>{
       res.status(500).send({
           message: "Negalima ištrinti naudotojo su id="+ id
       });
   });
}
```